# What is the best way to remove the first element from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have  string array (`String[]`) and I need to remove the first item. How can I do that efficiently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove objects from an Array in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Not a dupe.  The previous question is about removing items by value; this is about removing an item by index.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The size of arrays in Java cannot be changed.  So, technically you cannot remove any elements from the array.

One way to simulate removing an element from the array is to create a new, smaller array, and then copy all of the elements from the original array into the new, smaller array.

```
String[] yourArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArr, 1, oldArr.length);
```

**However**, I would not suggest the above method.  You should really be using a `List<String>`.  Lists allow you to add and remove items from any index.  That would look similar to the following:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // or LinkedList<String>();
list.add("Stuff");
// add lots of stuff
list.remove(0); // removes the first item
```

Comment: It is important to note that removing the first element of an `ArrayList` is O(n).

Comment: @Matt, for an array and the list.  But, the code is way easier for the list.

Comment: For an array and an `ArrayList`, but not for `LinkedList`.

Comment: @matt, oh yeah.  I always forget about that option.

Comment: O(n) ? well.. in a C array? to remove the fist element you can just increment the pointer O(1)

Comment: if a JDK method only return "String[]" not return "List<String>", then copyOfRange is the better option?

Comment: @CongDePeng Well, you can use Arrays.asList to turn your array into a List.

Comment: For those whom using Java for Android like me, [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) is for API9+

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen nice. Just to add to it, removal of only last element would be O(1). It is because `ArrayList` internally is represented by an array.

Comment: @HernánEche not really no, you need to either reallocate or shift left, both operations are O(n) ;)

Answer (score 16):

Simplest way is probably as follows - you basically need to construct a new array that is one element smaller, then copy the elements you want to keep to the right positions.

```
int n=oldArray.length-1;
String[] newArray=new String[n];
System.arraycopy(oldArray,1,newArray,0,n);
```

Note that if you find yourself doing this kind of operation frequently, it could be a sign that you should actually be using a different kind of data structure, e.g. a linked list. Constructing a new array every time is an O(n) operation, which could get expensive if your array is large. A linked list would give you O(1) removal of the first element.

An alternative idea is not to remove the first item at all, but just increment an integer that points to the first index that is in use. Users of the array will need to take this offset into account, but this can be an efficient approach. The Java String class actually uses this method internally when creating substrings.

Comment: This is not technically the easiest way.  `Arrays.copyOfRange()` is.

Comment: Since he is using Java6, he can use the more compact Arrays.copyOfRange

Comment: @Justin - sure but only if you are targeting Java 1.6 or above

Comment: true.  It isn't always applicable.

Comment: the title of the question makes it clear that the OP **is** interested in answers for Java 1.6 and above.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it at all, let alone quickly.  Arrays in Java are fixed size.  Two things you could do are:

1. Shift every element up one, then set the last element to null.
2. Create a new array, then copy it.

You can use `System.arraycopy` for either of these.  Both of these are O(n), since they copy all but 1 element.

If you will be removing the first element often, consider using [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) instead.  You can use [`LinkedList.remove`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28%29), which is from the `Queue` interface, for convenience.  With `LinkedList`, removing the first element is O(1).  In fact, removing any element is O(1) once you have a `ListIterator` to that position.  However, accessing an arbitrary element by index is O(n).

Answer (score 4):

Keep an index of the first "live" element of the array. Removing (pretending to remove) the first element then becomes an `O(1)` time complexity operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method you can use that is simple and uses less behind-the-scenes magic than the other answers here:

```
public String[] removeFirstFromArray(String[] arrayToRemoveFrom) {
    String[] newArray = new String[arrayToRemoveFrom.length - 1];
    for(int i = 1; i < arrayToRemoveFrom.length; i++) {
        newArray[i - 1] = arrayToRemoveFrom[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To sum up, the quick linkedlist method:

```
List<String> llist = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(oldArray));
llist.remove(0);
```

Comment: The question is about Java arrays, not list

Answer (score -13):

An alternative ugly method:

```
String[] a ={"BLAH00001","DIK-11","DIK-2","MAN5"};
String[] k=Arrays.toString(a).split(", ",2)[1].split("]")[0].split(", ");
```

Comment: Please, someone with sufficient reputation downvote this answer - it is exactly what it says it is - ugly! No intention to be rude, but in the interests of codeability please don't post this kind of thing!

Comment: if you are already using Arrays, it would be better to use Arrays.copyOfRange

Comment: He asked for the **best** way.

Comment: delete it, and see how much reputation you will gain.

Comment: no!! you already know its ugly then don't show it

Comment: This doesn't work if a string within the array contains `", "`.