# Remove Null Value from String array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

How to remove null value from String array in java?

```
String[] firstArray = {"test1","","test2","test4",""};
```

I need the "firstArray" without null ( empty) values like this

```
String[] firstArray = {"test1","test2","test4"};
```

Comment: `null` is completely different from "empty string" in Java. That's your first problem.

Comment: null is not "". "" is an empty, but perfectly valid string.

Comment: There is no null value in that array. There is, however, an empty sting (a non-null String object with a length of 0). Anyway, *what* have you tried?

Comment: yes you are right. null is different from "". just i wanted to removed all empty strings and should get another "String Array" without Empty strings as i mentioned.

Comment: Then you might want to update your question to reflect the fact that you mean empty string and not null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove objects from an Array in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you want to avoid fencepost errors and avoid moving and deleting items in an array, here is a somewhat verbose solution that uses `List`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RemoveNullValue {
  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    String[] firstArray = {"test1", "", "test2", "test4", "", null};

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String s : firstArray) {
       if(s != null && s.length() > 0) {
          list.add(s);
       }
    }

    firstArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
  }
}
```

Added `null` to show the difference between an empty String instance (`""`) and `null`.

Since this answer is around 4.5 years old, I'm adding a Java 8 example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RemoveNullValue {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        String[] firstArray = {"test1", "", "test2", "test4", "", null};

        firstArray = Arrays.stream(firstArray)
                     .filter(s -> (s != null && s.length() > 0))
                     .toArray(String[]::new);    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

It seems no one has mentioned about using `nonNull` method which also can be used with `streams` in **Java 8** to remove null (but not empty) as:

```
String[] origArray = {"Apple", "", "Cat", "Dog", "", null};
String[] cleanedArray = Arrays.stream(firstArray).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(origArray));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cleanedArray));
```

And the output is:

> [Apple, , Cat, Dog, , null]
>
> [Apple, , Cat, Dog, ]

If we want to incorporate empty also then we can define a utility method (in class `Utils`(say)):

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String string) {
        return (string != null && string.isEmpty());
    }
```

And then use it to filter the items as:

```
Arrays.stream(firstArray).filter(Utils::isEmpty).toArray(String[]::new);
```

I believe Apache common also provides a utility method `StringUtils.isNotEmpty` which can also be used.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(firstArray).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new);`     Worked for me.. great workaround when you have to work with an array rather than a list in already defined function that you dont want to rewrite.

Answer (score 20):

If you actually want to add/remove items from an array, may I suggest a `List` instead?

```
String[] firstArray = {"test1","","test2","test4",""};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : firstArray)
    if (!s.equals(""))
        list.add(s);
```

Then, if you *really* need to put that back into an array:

```
firstArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Haha. You implemented what I described! :-) My one improvement would be to pass a `new String[0]` to the `toArray` though -- it will create a new array with the correct size as needed.

Comment: You should use `String.isEmpty()` instead of `String.equals("")`

Comment: @Steve, lots of people feel the way you do.  I just (personally) think that `s.equals("")` is more readable -- less abstract.

Comment: @DaveJarvis, it's rather self-evident that the OP was confusing the empty string with `null`.

Comment: You're right, Kirk. Yet the possibility of a `NullPointerException` remains. That is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Using Google's [guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
String[] firstArray = {"test1","","test2","test4","",null};

Iterable<String> st=Iterables.filter(Arrays.asList(firstArray),new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String arg0) {
        if(arg0==null) //avoid null strings 
            return false;
        if(arg0.length()==0) //avoid empty strings 
            return false;
        return true; // else true
    }
});
```

Comment: Along the same approach, one could use the FunctionalJava library.

Comment: @Emil And then, how do you put what is inside `st` back inside `firstArray`?

Comment: @Abdull: No need for that since firstArray is not modified.The filtering happen's lazily.i.e while iterating the array.

Comment: if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(str))     return false; could be used instead of if(arg0==null) //avoid null strings 
            return false;
        if(arg0.length()==0) //avoid empty strings 
            return false;

Answer (score 4):

This is the code that I use to remove null values from an array which does not use array lists.

```
String[] array = {"abc", "def", null, "g", null}; // Your array
String[] refinedArray = new String[array.length]; // A temporary placeholder array
int count = -1;
for(String s : array) {
    if(s != null) { // Skips over null values. Add "|| "".equals(s)" if you want to exclude empty strings
        refinedArray[++count] = s; // Increments count and sets a value in the refined array
    }
}

// Returns an array with the same data but refits it to a new length
array = Arrays.copyOf(refinedArray, count + 1);
```

Comment: There is an off-by-one error in last line. Should be `count + 1`

Answer (score 3):

Quite similar approve as already posted above. However it's easier to read.

```java
/**
 * Remove all empty spaces from array a string array
 * @param arr array
 * @return array without ""
 */
public static String[] removeAllEmpty(String[] arr) {
    if (arr == null)
        return arr;

    String[] result = new String[arr.length];
    int amountOfValidStrings = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!arr[i].equals(""))
            result[amountOfValidStrings++] = arr[i];
    }

    result = Arrays.copyOf(result, amountOfValidStrings);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It might be readable. However code looks little verbose.

Answer (score 1):

A gc-friendly piece of code:

```
public static<X> X[] arrayOfNotNull(X[] array) {
    for (int p=0, N=array.length; p<N; ++p) {
        if (array[p] == null) {
            int m=p; for (int i=p+1; i<N; ++i) if (array[i]!=null) ++m;
            X[] res = Arrays.copyOf(array, m);
            for (int i=p+1; i<N; ++i) if (array[i]!=null) res[p++] = array[i];
            return res;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

It returns the original array if it contains no nulls. It does not modify the original array.

Answer (score -1):

Those are zero-length strings, not null. But if you want to remove them:

```
firstArray[0] refers to the first element
firstArray[1] refers to the second element
```

You can move the second into the first thusly:

```
firstArray[0]  = firstArray[1]
```

If you were to do this for elements [1,2], then [2,3], etc. you would eventually shift the entire contents of the array to the left, eliminating element 0. Can you see how that would apply?

Comment: Then the question becomes: "How can you resize an Array in Java"? :-)

Comment: That doesn't really do what he wants. This just copies data around. It doesn't do anything to make the array smaller.

Comment: thanks. But if i know the position where empty will come, i can do as u said. But empty strings generating dynamically. I cant predict in which position empty ( zero-length) will come.

Comment: Yes, but `s.size() == 0` will tell you a string is zero-length. The idea was for you to iterate through the array shifting elements over zero-length elements. The question was so trivial I assumed it was homework and didn't want to give you the whole answer, but apparently that's what's getting voted up. *shrug*