# Delete null element in 2d array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, resize

Help me please!,
i have this array of strings:

```
data2[3][2] = 
[[Datos Varios, Datos Empresa, null], 
[Listado2, Listado2 extendido, null], 
[Pendientes Validar, Pendientes Liquidar, Liquidados], 
[Pendientes Aprobar, Pendientes Pago, Pagados]]
```

i will found something for resize this array for obtain this:
i dont know the way..

```
data2[?][?] = 
[[Datos Varios, Datos Empresa], 
[Listado2, Listado2 extendido], 
[Pendientes Validar, Pendientes Liquidar, Liquidados], 
[Pendientes Aprobar, Pendientes Pago, Pagados]]
```

thanks in advance !!

Comment: This sentence 'i will found something for delete a null elements in my array for obtain this:' Is confusing to say the least. Secondly, null means nothing, you cannot delete nothing. It's like killing a dead-man, not possible, guy is already dead, leave him alone. Presuming that is what you meant.

Comment: @WeareBorg OP has array indicies not populated by an Object. They want the following objects moved up in line to replace those empty slots, with total array size reduced. Though admittedly, the best way to handle this is to handle null indicies where the array is consumed.

Comment: Who on earth is OP, I presume you mean operation. Ok, so you have statically declared the size of array, and now you see null entries. Presuming that is the situation, you can simply run a for loop and sort it. Is that what you want?

Comment: @WeareBorg OP means Original Poster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Null Value from String array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150233/remove-null-value-from-string-array-in-java)

Comment: ..or duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230315/how-to-remove-null-from-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought your problem is possibly with the 2d structure of your array, and the suggested links are 1d. So here is a suggested solution for the 2d case build with simple test on your data.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] data = 
        {{"Datos Varios", "Datos Empresa", null}, 
        {"Listado2", "Listado2 extendido", null}, 
        {"Pendientes Validar", "Pendientes Liquidar", "Liquidados"},
        {"Pendientes Aprobar", "Pendientes Pago", "Pagados"}};

        String[][] cleanedData = removeNull(data);

        System.out.println("Before");
        printArray(data);
        System.out.println("after");
        printArray( cleanedData );
    }

    public static void printArray(String[][] arr2d){
        for(String[] arr1d: arr2d){
            for(String s: arr1d){
                System.out.print(s+", ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public static String[][] removeNull( String[][] arr2d) {
        //
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list2d = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        //
        for(String[] arr1d: arr2d){
            ArrayList<String> list1d = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String s: arr1d){
                if(s != null && s.length() > 0) {
                    list1d.add(s);
                }
            }
            // you will possibly not want empty arrays in your 2d array
            // so I removed them
            if(list1d.size()>0){
                list2d.add(list1d);
            }
        }
        String[][] cleanArr = new String[list2d.size()][];
        int next = 0;
        for(ArrayList<String> list1d: list2d){
            cleanArr[next++] = list1d.toArray(new String[list1d.size()]);
        }
        return cleanArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow is perfect for my code!, so sorry if u or somebody not understand really good my question, but this solved my problem 100% love you.

Comment: @Drewico, I am glad to help. Good luck in your project.