# How to create a shorter array based on another?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array like this (source)

```
[Maria Carolina, Luisa Joana, Lara Silva, Catarina Patricio, Paula Castro, fim, null, null, null]
```

and I want an array like that (destination)

```
[Maria Carolina, Luisa Joana, Lara Silva, Catarina Patricio, Paula Castro]
```

In the following code `i` is the number of names.
My code is:

```
String[] nomeCompleto = new String[10];
String[] nomes = new String[10-i];
if(i < 10) {
    nomes[i] = nomeCompleto[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nomes));

return;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Could not find any relationship between your code and question. So a probable answer would be **everything**

Comment: I need to have a new array shorter

Comment: What are the rules for creating shorter array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove null from an array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230315/how-to-remove-null-from-an-array-in-java)

Comment: I need to have all the names until end not included

Comment: If `i` is the number of names, and thus the desired size of the output, why are you creating an output array of length `10-i`? If you want to copy a bunch of elements, you probably want a loop. How do you expect to copy many elements with just an if-statement?

Comment: Not really sure if OP wants to remove `nulls` from original array as the original array has a value **fim** which is not present in the output array - but that might just be a typo.

Comment: It's wrong I get it.

Comment: I need to take fim and null

Comment: Duplicate of [get only part of an Array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11001720)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit:** The question presents a source code fragment based on array indices, hence my original answer:

Use the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class to do this for you.

```
String[] names = new String[] {"Maria Carolina", "Luisa Joana", "Lara Silva", "Catarina Patricio", "Paula Castro", "fim", null, null, null};
String[] truncated = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(names, names.length-4); // remove the last 4 names
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(truncated));
```

Try it online [here](https://ideone.com/nRGDFQ).

**Edit:** Since people (not the OP) weren't too happy with that, I added: Or, to match only names of the form `Firstname Lastname`, use a regex:

```
String[] input = new String[] {"Maria Carolina", "Luisa Joana", "Lara Silva", "Catarina Patricio", "Paula Castro", "fim", null, null, null};
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String name : input) {
    if(name != null && name.matches("^[A-Z][A-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+$"))
        namesList.add(name);
}
String[] namesArray = namesList.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray));
```

Try it online [here](https://ideone.com/b6BK5o).

**Edit:** Finally, since Dukeling commented on `fim` meaning `end` in Portuguese, a better solution might be:

Use a loop to find the first occurrence of `fim` and then truncate the array accordingly (as in the first code snippet in my answer).

```
String[] names = new String[] {"Maria Carolina", "Luisa Joana", "Lara Silva", "Catarina Patricio", "Paula Castro", "fim", null, null, null};
int newLength = names.length;
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if("fim".equals(names[i])) {
        newLength = i;
        break;
    }
}
String[] truncated = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(names, newLength);
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(truncated));
```

Try it online [here](https://ideone.com/mPEdJW).

Comment: does it remove "fim"

Comment: @nits.kk Have you clicked the link in my answer? Yes, it does remove `fim`. @everyoneelse I would appreciate some input on how I can improve my answer since you guys have downvoted.

Comment: Although I have not down-voted it, but still above solution assumes "fim" to be at the end of the array, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: This solution does literally what the OP asked – for the given input. One could use a regex – I will expand my answer.

Comment: @nits.kk "fim" is Portuguese for "end", and having a special character to indicate the end of an array is not unheard of (even if it seems unnecessary and error-prone here done like this). Assuming it's the end of the array seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Dukeling thanks for the info, its reasonable and answer is good so a upvote for the same from my end.

Answer (score -1):

As per the Question's understanding Problem statement is as follows

*Given a master array of String we need to return another array which contains the elements of master with null elements and element with value "fim" removed.*

There can be null elements in between and not neccessary in the last and same for the element "fim"

**Basic Algorithm**

1. iterate master array
2. count the number of null & fim elements, create copy array of size =
   master array size - null elements count
3. Check if the element is null if not null then add to copy array

   ```
   public String[] removeNullNFimElementsFromArray(String[] master) {
       int nullNFimCount = 0;
       int masterSize = master.length;
       for(int i = 0; i < masterSize; i++) {
           if(master[i] == null || "fim".equals(master[i])) {
               nullNFimCount++;
           }
       }
       int copySize = masterSize - nullNFimCount;
       String[] copyArray = new String[copySize];
       for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < masterSize; i++) {
           if(master[i] != null && !"fim".equals(master[i])) {
               copyArray[j] = master[i];
               j++;
           }
       }
       return copyArray;
   }
   ```