# split string with multiple separator

Tags: java, string, cpu-word

I want to split this String to words

> "public static 9 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);"

the problem is when I run my program the word after input is " " or space, next word is new. It seems like this :

> ```
> Kata 1 = public
> Kata 2 = static
> Kata 3 = 9
> Kata 4 = Scanner
> Kata 5 = input
> Kata 6 = 
> Kata 7 = new
> Kata 8 = Scanner
> Kata 9 = System
> ```

What I want is after "input" is directly to "new". Here is my code :

```
int index=0;
String kata [] = kalimat.split("\\s+|\\W+");
System.out.println("\nKata dalam kalimat : ");
for (String s:kata){
    System.out.println("Kata "+(index+1)+" = "+s);
    index++;
}
System.out.println("Jumlah kata : " + kata.length);
```

I know that the problem is delimiter that I used for .split()

I want the output will be :

> ```
> Kata 1 = public
> Kata 2 = static
> Kata 3 = 9
> Kata 4 = Scanner
> Kata 5 = input
> Kata 6 = new
> Kata 7 = Scanner
> Kata 8 = System
> ```

Comment: Just split by whitespaces and any unwanted special chars

Comment: @smit that's my string "public static 9 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);"

Comment: I misunderstood it. I thought its a piece of code

Comment: can u give me a suggestion what should I change in my delimiter?

Comment: just use regex for string split from Brian Roach answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is not a "word character" (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`), so `\\W+` sees it as "not a word" and ignores it.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

**Edit to add:** So the answer is ... use a set and add it. `[=\\s\\W]+`

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But can you give me suggestion what delimiter should I use.

Comment: May be you can use the same logic as above and and remove the empty value from the array like mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150233/remove-null-value-from-string-array-in-java)