# Find null in a arraylist whose datatype is dynamic and sort it in java

Tags: java

I'm saving data in a list , the data is from a json object who's data is based on what the user chooses in the php side and so its datatype can vary , so i want to check if this list has null values and sort it. How can i write a custom comparator which is generic for everytype of data.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write a custom comparator that's generic unless you have a common super class.

That is a super class that will have some value you can use to compare.

To check if a list has a null value you will have to iterate over it and remove the null elements manually.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic datatype is `Object`. A `List` of Object can hold any type of `Object`.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But it would hard later to sort or any other operation on your collection. You should be specific with type which is recommended after java 1.5 (generic comes). `List<Object>` is like List without type or generic type. You should bound you `List` by upper of lower bound which must be a good idea. For Example -

```
List<? extends Number> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here `numberList` is upper bounded which accepts the subtypes of Number, such as `Integer`, `Double`, and `Float`.

Comment: Actually this will not work. What will be used to compare each other? equals method? Hows that gonna work for all the different types?

Comment: A list of `Object` can't be sorted in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Keppil  I am strongly agree with you and My answer is completed

Comment: @Thihara I am agree with you and completed my answer.

Comment: how to check null value in a array whose datatype is unkown?

Comment: [you can simply remove the null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150233/remove-null-value-from-string-array-in-java) or better at the time of insertion just don't add the null at all.