# How to split the string with slash

Tags: java

How do I split the string using forward slash? I've tried with following code:

```
I have string String x="10/20//30;expecting values 10,20,30.

When I tried to split using x.split("/"); then it only splitting 10,20,"",30
When I tried to split using x.split("//"); then it only splitting 10/20,30.
```

Please help me to split correctly. Is there any way to skip the one slash if there are 2 slashes present?

Regards,
murali

Comment: You want to replace slashes by comma or do you want the values of ints?

Comment: i want value of ints :10,20,30 after split

Comment: A solution would be first splitting it using double slash: `x.split("//"):`, and then splitting each of the the results using one slash: `s[0].split("/");`.

The final array of results would be: 10, 20 and 30

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do

```
String[] array = x.split("/+");
```

Comment: I think this works, can you please tell me how it works?

Comment: It is a regular expression split where there is atleast one slash but can be more.

Comment: easy enough - it uses a `+` quantifer to match one or more `/` characters

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x = x.split("[/]+");` with only one slash? Or did I misunderstand sth?

Comment: Yep, actually character class unnecessary here :)

Answer (score 1):

Because I can't comment on previous answer:

I think it has to be like

`String[] s = x.split("/+");`

Because otherwise it would be a conversion from String Array to String, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your first approach and remove empty value from the result, in example by using the solution described here: [Remove Null Value from String array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150233/remove-null-value-from-string-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It's splitting fine when you use x.split("/") the problem is it is inserting a blank where the // slash is because of how the split works it will return an array of [10, 20, , 30].  Just either remove all blanks from the array or when you process just skip elements that are blank.