# What is the most efficient method to remove null values within an array.

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am curious what the most efficient method of removing null values in arrays is. Here is my current null(0) removal method.

```
public static int[] removeNull(int[] array){
        int j = 0;
        for( int i=0;  i<array.length;  i++ )
        {
            if (array[i] != 0)
                array[j++] = array[i];
        }
        int [] newArray = new int[j];
        System.arraycopy( array, 0, newArray, 0, j );
        return newArray;
}
```

What is this method performance? I was expecting it to be n.

Comment: check this out :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150233/remove-null-value-from-string-array-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your method's time complexity is `O(n)` - your loop has `n` (the length of the array) iterations, and copying an array requires time proportional to the size of the copied array, which in this case is `O(n)` in the worst case.

And you can't do better than that (in terms of time complexity), since you have to iterate over the entire array in order to locate the elements that should be removed.

If your goal is to reduce code complexity (i.e. write the shortest amount of code), you can use an `IntStream` (requires Java 8 or later):

```
public static int[] removeNull(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i != 0).toArray();
}
```

As Andreas commented, this solution has the advantage of leaving the original array unchanged.

Comment: Entirely agree. +1 However, code complexity can be improved by replacing last 3 lines with [`return Arrays.copyOf(array, j);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-)

Comment: would these mean that the entire array function works in 2n? Or does that not make any sense, sorry I am new to this efficiency stuff.

Comment: @Andreas well, if the goal is to reduce the amount of code, you can use an IntStream and solve the problem with a single line of code.

Comment: @joshLor yes, though `2n` is asymptotically `O(n)`.

Comment: so if I am getting this right 2n is the same thing as O(n) and 2n is also the same thing as O(n).

Comment: @Eran True, but I was sticking to plain non-stream Java, since so many on here are still pre-Java 8 Android users. --- One more +1 from me for adding stream solution. *(Wish I could do another +1)*

Comment: @joshLor `2n is the same thing as O(n) and 2n is also the same thing as O(n)` - you got that right, twice :)

Comment: *Suggested clarification:* Stream solution is for Java 8+, and has the advantage that it leaves original array unmodified.

Comment: @Eran I like the explanation, I did not even realize from the start that it's still `O(n)` even with copying, but this still traverses it twice. plus one

Answer (score 0):

```
Use filter method,

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RemoveNullValue {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        String[] firstArray = {"test1", "", "test2", "test4", "", null};

        firstArray = Arrays.stream(firstArray)
                     .filter(s -> (s != null && s.length() > 0))
                     .toArray(String[]::new);    

    }
}
```

Comment: An `int` is not very probable to be `null`. In fact, I don't expect this to compile.

Comment: can check int with value of 0 and need to use Java 8

Comment: Still won't make code compile, since input is an `int[]`, not an `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: can use Arrays.stream(arrayList).filter() for int[]
from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150233/remove-null-value-from-string-array-in-java)

String[] firstArray = {"test1", "", "test2", "test4", "", null};

        firstArray = Arrays.stream(firstArray)
                     .filter(s -> (s != null && s.length() > 0))
                     .toArray(String[]::new);

Comment: You should edit answer and fix it, rather than having (unformatted) code in a comment. Right now, answer is still wrong.