# deleting an object from an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of objects of my custom class and i want to delete a random object(chosen by some criteria). how do i do this and keep the array ordered? naturally, there would be shifting of elements towards the left but i don't quite get the deleting the element part and need help formulating the logic. this is what i am doing but for it doesn't work correctly :(

```
     public static void deleteRecord(Customer[] records, int AccId){
      int pos=0; // index
      boolean  found = false;
      for (int i=0; i<count; i++){ // count is the number of elements in the array
          if (records[i].get_accountid()==AccId){
              found = true;
              pos = i;
               break;
          }
      }
      if (!found)
          System.out.println("The Record doesn't exist");

      for (int j=pos+1; j<count; j++) {
           records[j-1]= records[j];
          }
```

Comment: Usually you should use a List if you plan to delete elements at random.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove objects from an Array in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just shift the elements to the left as this will overwrite the item to be deleted.

```
public void remove(Object[] a, int index) {
    for (int i = index + 1; i < a.length && a[i] != null; i++) {
        a[i - 1] = a[i];
    }
}
```

Assuming that the first `null` indicates the end of the elements.

Of course, this is O(n) time and there are data structures like LinkedList that can remove elements in O(1) time.

Comment: ... but in a LinkedList you still need `O(n)` time to find the element to delete, if it is not mear one of the ends.

Comment: Ah, true! I suppose if you were inside an iterator you could remove the element in constant time?

Comment: Matthew could you provide a complete example

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't just delete an element from an array, not without either leaving empty indices or creating a new array. I would create a new array and use [System.arraycopy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to simplify copying over your elements. Something like:

```
Object[] newArr = new Object[arr.length-1];
System.arraycopy(arr,0,newArr,0,index);
System.arraycopy(arr,index+1, newArr, index, newArr.length - index);
return newArr;
```

Where `arr` is your original array and `index` is the random index to remove. Basically, it copies all elements up to the index to remove, and then copies all elements after the index. You can wrap this up in a separate method for simplicity. (Instead of using `arraycopy`, you could use two for-loops to accomplish the same thing).

I strongly suggest as others have to use a [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which simplifies adding and removing elements.

Comment: we are not allowed to use List collection for this assignment

Comment: note System.arraycopy is faster then manually copying arrays, as it is implemented natively.

Answer (score 1):

use List collection e.g:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
int toDelete = getRandomIndex(lst.size()); //your own implementation 
if (toDelete >= 0) {
    list.remove(toDelete); // it'll remove and shift elements
}
```

documentation about List.remove(int):

> Removes the element at the specified
>   position in this list (optional
>   operation). Shifts any subsequent
>   elements to the left (subtracts one
>   from their indices). Returns the
>   element that was removed from the
>   list.

Comment: unfortunately not allowed to use list collection. i edited the question...my code doesn't seem to work.help will appreciated