# How to remove element from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array for example:

```
String [][] test = {{"a","1"},
                    {"b","1"},
                    {"c","1"}};
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove an element from the array. For example I want to remove item "b", so that the array looks like:

```
{{"a","1"},
 {"c","1"}}
```

I can't find a way of doing it.  What I have found here so far is not working for me :(

Comment: You better use an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove objects from an Array in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot remove an element from an array.  The size of a Java array is determined when the array is allocated, and cannot be changed.  The best you can do is:

- Assign `null` to the array at the relevant position; e.g.

  ```
  test[1] = null;
  ```

  This leaves you with the problem of dealing with the "holes" in the array where the `null` values are.  (In some cases this is not a problem ... but in most cases it is.)
- Create a new array with the element removed; e.g.

  ```
  String[][] tmp = new String[test.length - 1][];
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
      if (i != indexOfItemToRemove) {
          tmp[j++] = test[i];
      }
  }
  test = tmp;
  ```

  The Apache Commons `ArrayUtils` class has some static methods that will do this more neatly (e.g. [`Object[] ArrayUtils.remove(Object[], int)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int%29), but the fact remains that this approach creates a new array object.

A better approach would be to use a suitable `Collection` type.  For instance, the `ArrayList` type has a method that allows you to remove the element at a given position.

Answer (score 8):

There is no built-in way to "remove" items from a regular Java array.

What you want to use is an [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could set the entry in the array to `null` (`test[0][1] = null;`). However, "removing" the item such that the array will have one element less than before is not doable without recreating the array. If you plan to change data in the data structure regularly an `ArrayList` (or another Collection class depending on your needs) might be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

You cannot remove an element from an array => it's correct, but we can do something to change current array.

```
No need assign null to the array at the relevant position; e.g.

test[1] = null;

Create a new array with the element removed; e.g.

String[][] temp = new String[test.length - 1][];
```

Need to get index at string/array to remove: IndexToRemove

```
for (int i = 0; i < test.length-1; i++) {
                if (i<IndexToRemove){
                    temp[i]=test[i];
                }else if (i==IndexToRemove){
                    temp[i]=test[i+1];
                }else {
                    temp[i]=test[i+1];
                }
}
test = temp;
```

Hope it helpful!