# How to manipulate volley response in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-volley

I want to add two features into my listview :-

> 1)On Long click I want to delete the row.
>
> 2)And once the row is
>   deleted I want to change the document numbers so that it is always in
>   order.
>
> For eg:- I have a list with doc_no IN1000,IN1001,IN1002 and I
>   delete the row with doc_no IN1001. What I would like to do is change
>   the doc_no of IN1002 to IN1001.So that it is always in a sequence.

So far I am successfully able to delete a row using parent.removeViewInLayout(view); but there is a problem if I scroll the listview  I get the deleted row back.

This is my code for deleting the row :-

```
lv_bsall.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
    {
        final int pos = position;
        final Dialog delete_expense = new Dialog(ReportGenerator.this);
        delete_expense.setContentView(R.layout.delete_payment);
        delete_expense.setTitle("DO YOUY WANT TO DELETE Invoice");
        Button yes = (Button) delete_expense.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                parent.removeViewInLayout(view);
                doc_no = ArrayUtils.removeElement(doc_no,doc_no[pos]);
                balance =ArrayUtils.removeElement(balance,balance[pos]);
                total =ArrayUtils.removeElement(total,total[pos]);
                vat =ArrayUtils.removeElement(vat,vat[pos]);
                profit=ArrayUtils.removeElement(profit,profit[pos]);

                delete_expense.dismiss();

            }
        });

        Button no = (Button) delete_expense.findViewById(R.id.no);
        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                delete_expense.dismiss();
            }
        });

        delete_expense.show();



        return true;
    }
});
```

This is the method I call on response :-

```
public void showBS(String response) {
    ParseBS_all pb = new ParseBS_all(response);
    pb.parseBS();

    doc_no =ParseBS_all.doc_no;
    balance =ParseBS_all.balance;
    total =ParseBS_all.total;
    vat=ParseBS_all.vat;
    profit=ParseBS_all.profit;

    bl = new BS_allList(this, doc_no, balance, total, vat, profit);
    lv_bsall.setAdapter(bl);
}
```

And this is code for my Adapter class for the list:-

```
public class BS_allList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    private String[] doc_no;
    private String[] balance;
    private String[] total;
    private String[] vat;
    private String[] profit;
    private Activity context;

    public BS_allList(Activity context, String[] doc_no, String[]balance, String[] total, String[] vat, String[] profit)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.bs_list_all, doc_no);
        this.context =context;
        this.doc_no= doc_no;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.total = total;
        this.vat=vat;
        this.profit = profit;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View listViewItem, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (null == listViewItem)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bs_list_all, null, true);
        }
        TextView tv_docNo = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvdoc_no);
        TextView tv_balance = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_balance);
        TextView tv_tot = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
        TextView tv_vat = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_vat);
        TextView tv_pf = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_profit);

        tv_docNo.setText(doc_no[position]);
        tv_balance.setText(balance[position]);
        tv_tot.setText(total[position]);
        tv_vat.setText(vat[position]);
        tv_pf.setText(profit[position]);


        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

I am new to programming so any Help or suggestion is most appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Remove from parent is not enough, you need to remove it from data also so remove it from your string arrays also, or better way is use List instead of so much string arrays so you can easily do this

Comment: I tried doing exactly that using this code :-doc_no = ArrayUtils.removeElement(doc_no,doc_no[pos]);
//                        balance = ArrayUtils.removeElement(balance,balance[pos]);
//                        total =ArrayUtils.removeElement(total,total[pos]);
//                        vat =ArrayUtils.removeElement(vat,vat[pos]);
//                        profit=ArrayUtils.removeElement(profit,profit[pos]); but it did not work

Comment: write same in your above code and update so i can check exactly what you have written as here in comment not possible it

Comment: @Vickyexpert I have updated my question please check.

Comment: that is wrong way your are deleting, check below post for same, by this way element will not removed from arra,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935168/how-to-remove-element-from-an-array

do one thing print lenght of array before deleting element and then print again after deleting so you will get exact idea

Comment: I think you need to use List<> collection for this

Comment: I think you need to change your question title to delete a row from list or something.. So it can be helpful to other users also.. because according to my understanding no need of manipulating Volley response here..!! @AndroidNewBee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using ArrayList should be helpful in your case. Please try this solution.It addresses both your requirements:-

```
  public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ls_docno = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(doc_no));
                ls_balance = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(balance));
                ls_total =new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(total));
                ls_vat= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(vat));
                ls_profit =new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(profit));

                ls_docno.remove(pos);
                ls_balance.remove(pos);
                ls_total.remove(pos);
                ls_profit.remove(pos);
                ls_vat.remove(pos);

                Log.d("POSITION",String.valueOf(pos));

                for (int i=pos; i< ls_docno.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(i>0)
                    {
                        String doc= ls_docno.get(i-1);
                        String inv_no = doc.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                        int new_invno = Integer.parseInt(inv_no);
                        new_invno++;
                        ls_docno.set(i,"IN"+new_invno);

                    }

                }

                doc_no = ls_docno.toArray(new String[ls_docno.size()]);
                balance = ls_balance.toArray(new String[ls_balance.size()]);
                total = ls_total.toArray(new String[ls_total.size()]);
                profit = ls_profit.toArray(new String[ls_profit.size()]);
                vat = ls_profit.toArray(new String[ls_vat.size()]);

                bl = new BS_allList(ReportGenerator.this, doc_no, balance, total, vat, profit);
                lv_bsall.setAdapter(bl);


                delete_expense.dismiss();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a method **in your adapter** called `deleteRow` and pass `position` as am argument. Like this:

```
public void deleteRow(int position)
{
    doc_no = ArrayUtils.removeElement(doc_no, doc_no[position]);
    total = ArrayUtils.removeElement(total, total[position]);
    balance = ArrayUtils.removeElement(balance, balance[position]);
    vat = ArrayUtils.removeElement(vat, vat[position]);
    profit = ArrayUtils.removeElement(profit, profit[position]);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

call it in your **LongClick** :

```
 yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {                
           // Here 'bl' is the object of your 'BS_allList' adpater

            bl.deleteRow(position);
            parent.removeViewInLayout(view);
            delete_expense.dismiss();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I get an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2