# Java Remove ArrayList by Value

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList like this:

> [{1=R111, 2=Red, 3=50000}, {1=R123, 2=Blue , 3=50000}]

and i want to remove the array by value (R111 or R123).

how to remove the array using array.remove method for array like that?

I've try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)
but it's doesn't work for my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove objects from an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)

Comment: 5 seconds on google would have found you this: [inline link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: @Stefan no, it's different array.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You have an `ArrayList` containing arrays and you want to remove an array from the `ArrayList` based on a value in the array? So your result would be `[{1=R123, 2=Blue , 3=50000}]` when you remove based on  ` R111`?

Comment: @Pieter yes, i want to remove the ArrayList based on a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `ArrayList` is this:

```
List<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new String[]{"R111","Red","50000"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"R123","Blue","50000"});
```

you can do something like:

```
for (Iterator<String[]> iterator = arrayList.iterator();iterator.hasNext();) {
    String[] stringArray = iterator.next();
    if("R111".equals(stringArray[0])) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

You can safely remove an element using `iterator.remove()` while iterating the `ArrayList`. Also see [The collection Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html).

An alternative shorter approach using `Streams` would be:

```
Optional<String[]> array = arrayList.stream().filter(a -> "R111".equals(a[0])).findFirst();
array.ifPresent(strings -> arrayList.remove(strings));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks pieter, I used Iterator like this:

```
for (Iterator<HashMap<String, String>> iterator = RegulerMenu.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    HashMap<String, String> stringArray = iterator.next();
            if("R111".equals(stringArray.get("1"))) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
```

It's work now, Thankyou verymuch.