# How to compare two arrays using a for loop and keep the unique from first array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

how to compare two array value and remove the duplicate value from the first array using php for example

```
$a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$b = ['a','e'];

$result_array = ['b','c','d','f'];
```

I tried this:

```
$a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$b = ['a','e'];

foreach($a as $key_a=>$val_a){
  $val = '';
  foreach($b as $key_b=>$val_b){
      if($val_a != $val_b){
        $val = $val_a;    
            }else{$val = $val_b;}

  }
  echo $val."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate, but I'm bored.  Just compute the difference:

```
$a = array_diff($a, $b);
```

Or loop the main array, check for each value in the other and if found unset from the main array:

```
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    if(in_array($v, $b)) {
        unset($a[$k]);
    }
}
```

Or loop the other array, search for each value in the main array and use the key found to unset it:

```
foreach($b as $v) {
    if(($k = array_search($v, $a)) !== false) {
        unset($a[$k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"This is probably a duplicate, but I'm bored"* I know exactly how that feels :-). Plus it often takes longer to find the dupe than post the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this SO post look at the Edit3 
[Edit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)
We used this code to compare two ArrayList and remove the duplicates from one as we only wanted the misspelled words
Example of code capture is a ArrayList

```
    for(int P = 0; P < capture.size();P++){

    String gotIT = capture.get(P);     
    String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = new String[0];
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list, strArray);
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(gotIT));
    strArray = list.toArray(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY); 
    // Code above removes the correct spelled words from ArrayList capture
    // Leaving the misspelled words in strArray then below they are added 
    // to the cboMisspelledWord which then holds all the misspelled words
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `$b` a dictionary, which will has better performance when the two array has many elements.   Check the [Demo](https://3v4l.org/u1C5q)

```
$a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$b = ['a','e'];
$dic = array_flip($b);
$result = array_filter($a, function($v)use($dic){return !isset($dic[$v]);});
print_r($result);
```