# How to delete an image from an array

Tags: java, arrays, xml, image, android-studio

Peace, mercy and blessings of God

How to delete an image from an array

Example

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket, R.drawable.ic_basket};
```

null method did not succeed and sends a mistake

```
images[x] = null;
images[x] = Integer.parseInt(null);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new array and copy all other images to it:

```
int imageToRemove = ....;
int[] newImages = new int[images.length - 1];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < newImages.length; i++) {
    if (images[i] == imageToRemove)
        count++;
    newImages[i] = images[count++];
}
images = newImages;
```