# How do I remove int values from array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried converting it to array list and back using this

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/conversion-of-array-to-arraylist-in-java/

but I'm getting a lot of error, I also tried this

[How do I remove objects from an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)

but it only works on strings for some reason, I did modify to make it for int but it's not working

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(3));
array = list.toArray(array);
```

What I'm trying to do is this

```
        // copy 2 elements in array1 to array2
        // remove those 2 elements from array1 since I already used them
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List<int[]>)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to int)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(Collection<? extends Integer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; inference variable T has incompatible bounds
          upper bounds: Integer,Object
          lower bounds: int[])
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)

No idea what this is talking about

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert int\[\] into List<Integer> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Conversions to and from lists, etc., are very roundabout ways.  All you need to do is to make a new array, omitting the entries you don't want.

In the simple case where you want to remove a single unique value:

```
int[] array = { 1,2,3,4 };
int[] newArray = new int[array.length - 1];
for (int i=0, j=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] != 3)
        newArray[j++] = array[i];
}
```

Regard this as an example from which you can construct your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

Can use you the functtion get using index?

```
   ArrayList.get(index)
```

and then remove it from the list

```
   ArrayList.remove(index)
```

Comment: How do I do that? I'm a beginner, also my array isn't an array list yet, I'm having trouble converting it to an array list

Comment: I think this code can help you:

       Integer [] array = {1, 2, 3,4};

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));

        int numberOne = list.get(0); // return 1
        list.remove(0); // remove it
        System.out.println(numberOne);

Answer (score 0):

```java
Integer[] array = { 1,2,3,4 };
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
integerList.removeAll(List.of(1,2));
        
array = integerList.toArray(new Integer[integerList.size()]);
```

You have to replace old array with new (different length).

Comment: directly copied this code I'm getting error on this line
integerList.removeAll(List.of(1,2)); "of" is unknown

Comment: What is your java version?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it if you need to get back to an array of primitives (int instead of Integer).

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4};
int[] array2 = {3};

Set<Integer> numbersToRemove = IntStream.of(array2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

array = IntStream.of(array).boxed().filter(e -> !numbersToRemove.contains(e)).mapToInt(e -> e).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java generics does not work for primitives; as such, your int array is treated as one object for `Arrays.asList`, so it returns `List<int[]>`. You can use streams and filter for this purpose.

```
final List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().filter(i->i!=3).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/4COT3d)

If you need to remove more than one number, you can store them in a `Set`.

```
final Set<Integer> shouldRemove = Set.of(3, 6, 7, 10);
final List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().filter(i->!shouldRemove.contains(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's calling `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)` which can take multiple arguments but you're only passing the 1 of the type `int[]` and thus type `T` is of that type.

You can verify this:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).get(0)[0]); // returns 1
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).get(0)[1]); // returns 2
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).get(0)[2]); // returns 3
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).get(0)[3]); // returns 4
```

Java is pretty dumb when it comes to primitives and what you want to do with them. Primitives cannot be a type in Java so it's doing the best it can in an effort to get you what you're asking of it.

Change your int[] to an Integer[] and it should work.

```java
Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```