# Removed card from hand in poker?

Tags: java

How can I remove a card from an array in poker? Everything I've seen so far uses the "remove" method, but I am working with arrays and am not allowed to use that.

Here is my code so far:

```
private String name;
private int wins;
private Card[] hand;
private int cardsInHand;

public Player(String newName){
        name = newName;
        wins = 0;
        hand = new Card[5]
        cardsInHand = 0;
    }

    public void removeCard(Card cardToRemove){

    }
```

Comment: You'll have to traverse the array until you find the element you're looking for (suppose it's at index `n`) then you have to move the element at `hand[n+1]` to `hand[n]`, then the one at `hand[n+2]` to `hand[n+1]` and so on, then put the last element at `null`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove objects from an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java) (there are array-only answers further down)

Answer (score 0):

## Locate

First, locate the desired `Card` object in the array. To do so, your `Card` class must override the `equals` method (and `hashCode`) inherited from `Object`.

Or, in Java 16+, define your card class as a [`record`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). The compiler implicitly creates an override of `equals` (and `hashCode`) that examines each and every of the member fields.

Locate an existing `Card` object match by looping the array. Test each `Card` object in the array for equality with the target `Card` object passed as an argument.

## Remove

Assigning `null` to a slot in your array clears any existing reference that may be stored there.

I expect that if you review your schoolwork notes and readings, you’ll find discussions about null.